# Incorrect? “I only have one distinct memory from the movie, a scene where …”

Tags: word-usage

Should I say “I only have one distinct memory from the movie, *that of* a scene where …”, or would it work without the *that of*? If it wouldn’t work without the *that of*, what if I replace the comma with a colon? Would it be ok then?

Comment: 'that' is a pronoun, that = memory. 'I have a memory of a scene...'. A colon would be inappropriate here.

Comment: Thanks. How about an em dash instead of the comma, would that work (i.e., would it allow me to leave out the "that of")?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It would work with or without the *that of*.

If the bit after the comma was an independent clause (it could be a sentence on its own), then a colon could be used.

You can also jump straight into the description with, e.g.:

> I only have one distinct memory from the movie, Maggie Gyllenhaal turning to look over her shoulder with a perfect expression of shocked outrage stifled by uncertainty.
>
> I only have one distinct memory from the movie: Maggie Gyllenhaal turns to look over her shoulder with a perfect expression of shocked outrage stifled by uncertainty.

Comment: Can't vote up due to my low reputation, but thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You might want to replace "I only have one" with "My only..."

> My only distinct memory from the movie is Bingley's proposal to Elizabeth.

Otherwise, a colon is a good option:

> I only have one distinct memory from the movie: a scene where...

Comment: Thanks, I'll consider that, too, and see how it fits with the rest of the paragraph. (The colon is a typo, I assume?)

Comment: @ertha Actually, I meant "colon," not semicolon. Sorry for the misleading typo.